# Search and replace formatted properties inside Java string

Tags: java, regex, string

I will be given Strings that contain formatted "properties"; that is, Strings encapsulated inside the standard "${" and "}" tokens:

> "This is an ${example} of a ${string} that I may be ${given}."

I will also have a `HashMap<String,String>` containing substitutions for each possible formatted property:

```
HashMap Keys           HashMapValues
===========================================
bacon                  eggs
ham                    salads
```

So that, given the following String:

> "I like to eat ${bacon} and ${ham}."

I can send this to a Java method that will transform it into:

> "I like to eat eggs and salads."

Here's my best attempt:

```
System.out.println("Starting...");

String regex = "$\\{*\\}";
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("bacon", "eggs");
map.put("ham", "salads");

String sampleString = "I like ${bacon} and ${ham}.";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sampleString);
while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found " + matcher.group());

    // Strip leading "${" and trailing "}" off.
    String property = matcher.group();

    if(property.startsWith("${"))
        property = property.substring(2);
    if(property.endsWith("}"))
        property = property.substring(0, property.length() - 1);

    System.out.println("Before being replaced, property is: " + property);

    if(map.containsKey(property))
        property = map.get(property);

    // Now, not sure how to locate the original property ("${bacon}", etc.)
    // inside the sampleString so that I can replace "${bacon}" with
    // "eggs".
}

System.out.println("Ending...");
```

When I execute this, I get no errors, but just see the "Starting..." and "Ending..." outputs. This tells me that my regex is incorrect, and so the `Matcher` isn't able to match any properties.

So my first question is: what should this regex be?

Once I'm past that, I'm not sure how to perform the string replace once I've changed "${bacon}" into "eggs", etc. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Trying to solve this problem with RegEx (if possible at all...) is an academical exercise, "in the real world" you should use an engine like e.g. http://freemarker.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
String regex = "\\$\\{([^}]*)\\}";
```

Then you obtain only the content between `${` and `}` that is inside the capture group 1.

Note that the `$` has a special meaning in a pattern: *end of the string*
Thus it musts be escaped to be seen as literal (as curly brackets).

Answer (score 6):

Why don't use a .properties file?, that way you could get all your messages from that file and could be separate from your code, something like (file example.properties):

```
message1=This is a {0} with format markers on it {1}
```

And then in your class load your bundle and use it like this:

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("example.properties", Locale.getDefault());
MessageFormat.format(bundle.getString('message1'), "param0", "param1"); // This gonna be your formatted String "This is a param0 with format markers on it param1"
```

You could use the MessageFormat (is a java.util library) without the bundle (just use the String directly), but again, having a bundle makes your code clear (and gives easy internationalization)

Answer (score 4):

Better use [StrSubstitutor](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrSubstitutor.html) from [apache commons lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/). It can also substitute System props.

Since commons-lang 3.6 StrSubstitutor has been deprecated in favour of [commons-text](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/) StringSubstitutor.  Example:

```
import org.apache.commons.text.StringSubstitutor;

Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("bacon", "eggs");
props.setProperty("ham", "salads");
String sampleString = "I like ${bacon} and ${ham}.";
String replaced = StringSubstitutor.replace(sampleString, props);
```

Comment: This is the simplest answer.  Use a library which someone else has tested.

Answer (score 2):

For completion, here is a working solution:

```
static final Pattern EXPRESSION_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{([^}]*)\\}");

/**
 * Replace ${properties} in an expression
 * @param expression expression string
 * @param properties property map
 * @return resolved expression string
 */
static String resolveExpression(String expression, Map<String, String> properties) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(expression.length());
    int i = 0;
    Matcher matcher = EXPRESSION_PATTERN.matcher(expression);
    while(matcher.find()) {
        // Strip leading "${" and trailing "}" off.
        result.append(expression.substring(i, matcher.start()));
        String property = matcher.group();
        property = property.substring(2, property.length() - 1);
        if(properties.containsKey(property)) {
            //look up property and replace
            property = properties.get(property);
        } else {
            //property not found, don't replace
            property = matcher.group();
        }
        result.append(property);
        i = matcher.end();
    }
    result.append(expression.substring(i));
    return result.toString();
}
```